# How to use the Solidity Burn function

Tags: solidity, tokens, smart-contract-wallets, burn

Newbie here,

Can someone explain how to use the Burn function in a solidity contract?
I have a token with 1 trillion supply and I would like to burn 1% when nessesary. The Function is asking for a amount = uinit256.
I am stuck on what the input would be. I have tried entering 10000000000 and it only burns 1 token.

[image: Burn Function]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most ERC20 tokens implicitly have 18 decimals, meaning "1 Token" actually means 1 * 10^18 tokens in solidity code. If you want to burn 1% of 10^12, you actually need to input 0.01 * 10^12 * 10^18 = 10^28. That's a 1 followed by 28 zeros: 10000000000000000000000000000

Please do the math for yourself and make sure this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a deeper look into the contract before posting questions.

ERC20 standard implementation (used by most people) defines balances as `uint256`.

You also have a function called `decimals` which allows for external agents to interpret `balanceOf` data as a decimal instead of an integer.

Example:

- `decimals() = 18` - as pointer out by @phaze, this is usually the case, although you can change it
- `balanceOf(someAddress) = 100`

In this case, Metamask and most websites will show you that you have `0.000...01` tokens, and not `100`. This is because they display your balance in the UI as `balanceOf(you)/(10^decimals())`.

But in Remix, this is not the case, so you have to enter `10^decimals()` to burn the amount you wish to burn.